# What does the # symbol mean in a Python list?

Tags: python, list, symbols

Why do we insert `#` in the `test_board`? We have just 9 positions, if I delete it, I get an error.

What does that `#` mean exactly?

Thanks

```
#from IPython.display import clear_output
def display1(board1):
    clear_output()
    print('Your Tic-Tac-Toe board now:\n')
    print (board1[7]+'|'+board1[8]+'|'+board1[9])
    print("________")
    print (board1[4]+'|'+board1[5]+'|'+board1[6])
    print("________")
    print (board1[1]+'|'+board1[2]+'|'+board1[3])
    print("________")

test_board=['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']
display1(test_board)
```

Comment: It looks like it's a placeholder in the 0th position because the code author wanted to count from 1, not 0. It's worth noting this code could be much better written.

Comment: It's just the normal character like 'X' etc

Answer (score 0):

"#" here simply means a character it is the zeroth character.

```
test_board[0]="#"
```

your code works with # because you are using one based indexing in the display
if you remove # from the list then you will have to use zero based indexing
like this

```
def display1(board1):
    clear_output()
    print('Your Tic-Tac-Toe board now:\n')
    print (board1[6]+'|'+board1[7]+'|'+board1[8])
    print("________")
    print (board1[3]+'|'+board1[4]+'|'+board1[5])
    print("________")
    print (board1[0]+'|'+board1[1]+'|'+board1[2])
    print("________")

test_board=['X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']
display1(test_board)
```

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks :)

Comment: No problem brother, btw you can accept my solution instead of saying thanks green tick bellow the upvote and downvote.